# JS require in QML

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qtquick2

I am using the **dbox** library in a QML app (sources available at [github](https://github.com/sintaxi/dbox)). In a QML file I import the dbox library with the following code:

```
import "./dbox-master/lib/dbox.js" as Dbox
```

Then I use it in this way:

```
var app   = Dbox.app({ "app_key": root.appKey, "app_secret": root.appSecret })
```

However, in the `dbox.js` there're series of `require` statements, at the top of the file:

```
define(['require', 'request', 'querystring', 'path'], function (require) {
    var request = require('request');
    var qs = require('querystring');
    var path = require('path');
    var helpers_ = require("./helpers")
//    var request = require('request');
});
//var request = require("request")
//var qs      = require("querystring")
//var path    = require("path")
//require(['request'], function (foo) {
//    console.log('request is loaded')
//});

exports.app = function(config){
  var root   = config.root  || "sandbox"
  var helpers = helpers_(config)

  return {
    root: root,

    requesttoken: function(cb){
      var signature = helpers.sign({})
      var body = qs.stringify(signature)
      var args = {
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": { 
          "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          "content-length": body.length
        },
        "url": "https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth/request_token",
        "body": body
      }
      return request(args, function(e, r, b){
        var obj = qs.parse(b)
        obj.authorize_url = "https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=" + obj.oauth_token
        cb(e ? null : r.statusCode, obj)
      })
    },...
```

As you see, I've changed the code to get the `dbox.js` to work but the `require` is not defined. How to use the `require.js` properly?

**Update**.
As I found out, the problem is in the host environment. The QML global space is constant. `Node.js` requires objects to be present in the space (e.g. iself) and importing into the global space. There is a [project on github](https://github.com/trollixx/node.qml) glueing `Node.js` and QML but it is not finished yet. I propose another solution: make a C++ plugin to run a script in js. The script is run in the `Node.js` environment to communicate Dropbox account information to the Quick-based application.

Answer (score 0):

What is the best approach to use a web API? `Dropbox` in this case.

It depends.

Since I need to list all files and download a file, the best choice is to use the `Dropbox` API manually.

I used `OAuth2` to authorize the application, the `Token Flaw`, because it is fast.

`WebView` was the app. built-in browser. Once a `redirect_uri` is set as the `WebView url` property value then it means the authorization is passed. The `access token` is returned with the redirection.

**Note.**
The `redirect_uri` must be equal to the `redirect_uri` set in the application `AppConsole` in the app. `Dropbox` account.

Result: I did not use the `3d party` `Dropbox JS` libraries, it is much faster to send requests manually.